# How to pass values in URL in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am redirecting to a page  changepassword, I want to pass the useremail and password in the url which I get in the current page. How can I pass it in the url. I dont want to use session or cookie.

```
 Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx");
```

Comment: I hope you plan to pass the password as `****` :)

Comment: @murthy i think u better not pass the password in the URL, as you can authenticate the user in one webform and the just pass the pasword to the changepassword page (for security purpose)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx?MyParam=MyValue");
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Please use **Session** object to keep this information!!!

Have a look [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Don't use

```
Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx?password=_543k@sdfPASS");
```

to send any security data!!!

Answer (score 1):

well you can append querystring parameters like this:

```
Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx?test=value1&test2=value2");
```

surely I would not put any password in there anyway...

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx?username=user&password=pass");` same as Querystring passed from Ajax.

but that's not a good idea

Comment: It isn't passed "from Ajax", you just pass key value pairs through the GET method

Comment: send the password this way and for sure you lose it !

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem yes sure ,but just an example where this Use-case can be present .

Comment: @Aristos im not suggesting it ,just show him how to achieve.If he does this way i may not take the responsibility ;)

Comment: to send it this way must be encrypted first.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `Response.Redirect` method supports a full URL as the parameter, so you can use:

```
Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx?Username=sweko&password=secret");
```

That will redirect the browser to that page, and the user will be free to inspect and modify the URL further, just the same as if he entered it manually.

There is absolutely nothing that will prevent the user to enter another user's username and there is no way that you'll be able to prevent a malicious onlooker from looking at the URL, so sending security information in the URL is a horrible, horrible idea.