# How tooo pass values in URL in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

example of my problem i have 2 textboxs, 1 for txtNombre  and 1 for txtArea..

WEBFORM1

txtNombre : ( george )
txtArea   : (        )
hyperlink (>>)
Button

WEBFORM2

BUTTON ( with the Area Value, when i hit this button in my WEBFORM1 it appear like this.)

WEBFORM1

txtNombre : (         )
txtArea   : ( Kitchen )
hyperlink (>>)
Button

im working with this value for de Area

```
>   ---WEBFORM1  txtBoton.Text = Request["variable"];

>  ----WEBFORM2  string Area = "Kitchen";
>  -----------   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?variable=" + Area);
```

this is the code for the Area
But i want to know how can i take the value of the textbox : txtNombre .  to the second webform and send it back to the webform1  .. i use a hyperlink to go to the webform ..

Comment: You sould search before asking.

Try this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726932/how-to-pass-values-in-url-in-c-sharp]

Comment: Thx :)!  ill investigate more:)

Comment: It's ok. That's how you learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should google harder next time:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

This is a sample code working with several params in QueryString and it shows them in the webpage:

```
int loop1, loop2;

// Load NameValueCollection object.
NameValueCollection coll=Request.QueryString; 
// Get names of all keys into a string array.
String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys; 
for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
{
    Response.Write("Key: " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr1[loop1]) + "<br>");
    String[] arr2 = coll.GetValues(arr1[loop1]);
    for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++) 
    {
         Response.Write("Value " + loop2 + ": " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]) + "   <br>");
    }
}
```

For example, if you have an URL like this: http://[Insert server name here]/Example.aspx?Param1=1&Param2=a&Param3=2

The output will be:

- Value 1: 1
- Value 2: a
- Value 3: 2

Comment: thx srry for asking that im a newbie :( amm still learning :) but thx for helping me :)